# JavaScript not working after Chrome update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I often accidentally close my Chrome browser and have to reopen and reload all the tabs that I'd been working on. Since Chrome does not a have built in confirm before closing mechanism, I wrote a simple page to ask for confirmation before closing. I leave that page open among my other tabs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p>This page is to prevent accidental closing of Chrome.</p>
        <script language="JavaScript">

            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return "Are you sure?";
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Recently I updated my Chrome browser from version 56 to 60. Now the code doesn't seem to work as it no longer asks for confirmation before closing. I tried many different variations from the internet but none seem to work.

Note: I am very new to web development.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @LewisBrowne No.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) :

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all.

So, I think your function is not guaranteed to run, especially because 
 Chrome 60 explicitly has that first behaviour. From the [notes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/chrome-60-deprecations#require_user_gesture_for_beforeunload_dialogs):

> From Chrome 60 onward, the beforeunload dialog will only appear if the frame attempting to display it has received a user gesture or user interaction (or if any embedded frame has received such a gesture).

So if you want to continue using this approach, you may need to interact with the page at some point in your session.

Alternatively, to open all the tabs you had open when you restart Chrome, try pressing [`Ctrl-Shift-T`](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/chrome/reopen-recently-closed-tabs-in-chrome/).

Comment: Yes, this is specifically mentioned among Chrome 60 changes/deprecations: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/chrome-60-deprecations#require_user_gesture_for_beforeunload_dialogs

Comment: Yes I noticed that, whenever I highlighted the text in the page and then closed, the confirmation box would appear. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Sure, I suppose you could use something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to automate some interaction. But really, I don't think you need to- Chrome allows you to `Continue where you left off` by opening the previous tabs when you open the window, so you shouldn't really lose anything by accidentally closing the window. Try checking your `chrome://settings` page and seeing if this is enabled.

Comment: I have about 30 to 40 tabs opened in Chrome at any given time. Most of them I've interacted with in one way or another. Reloading all these pages and the work I've done in them wastes a lot my time if I accidentally close them.